# How can i solve merging en pulling error?

Tags: merge, jupyter-notebook

I'm getting this error:

```
git mergetool docs/.ipynb_checkpoints/notebook-checkpoint.ipynb
Merging:
docs/.ipynb_checkpoints/notebook-checkpoint.ipynb

Normal merge conflict for 'docs/.ipynb_checkpoints/notebook-checkpoint.ipynb':
  {local}: modified file
  {remote}: modified file
The merge tool meld is not available as 'meld'
(base) -@MBP-van-PD infovis % git pull
error: Pulling is not possible because you have unmerged files.
hint: Fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
hint: as appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit.
fatal: Exiting because of an unresolved conflict.
type here
```

I don't know how to fix it, please help me out and be as precise as possible since i've nearly no experience.

i tried using other stack overflow explanations but there was no outcome